# Stack Overflow when invalidate options menu

Tags: android, stack-overflow

I got a crash report from a user. I have a weird problem. Stack overflows on invalidate options menu.

It looks invalidateOptionsMenu is a wrapper method an it makes recursive calls. I don't know how to handle it.

Here is the crash report from my user:

```
USER_COMMENT=null   
ANDROID_VERSION=4.1.2   
APP_VERSION_NAME=1.0  
BRAND=samsung   
PHONE_MODEL=GT-I9100

STACK_TRACE=java.lang.StackOverflowError  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1022)  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2131) at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:865)  at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:115) at com.geniboys.sosyaaal.ExplorerActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ExplorerActivity.java:309) at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2571)  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:455) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:829) at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2690)  at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:29) at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:649) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:171) at com.geniboys.sosyaaal.ExplorerActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ExplorerActivity.java:310) at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2571)  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:455) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:829) at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2690)  at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:29) at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:649) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:171) at com.geniboys.sosyaaal.ExplorerActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ExplorerActivity.java:310) at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2571)  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:455) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:829) at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2690)  at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:29) at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:649) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:171) at com.geniboys.sosyaaal.ExplorerActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ExplorerActivity.java:310) at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2571)  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:455) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:829) at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2690)  at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:29) at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:649) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:171) at com.geniboys.sosyaaal.ExplorerActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ExplorerActivity.java:310) at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2571)  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:455) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:829) at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2690)  at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:29) at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:649) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:171) at com.geniboys.sosyaaal.ExplorerActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ExplorerActivity.java:310) at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2571)  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:455) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:829) at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2690)  at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:29) at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:649) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:171) at com.geniboys.sosyaaal.ExplorerActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ExplorerActivity.java:310) at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2571)  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:455) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:829) at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2690)  at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:29) at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:649) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:171) at com.geniboys.sosyaaal.ExplorerActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ExplorerActivity.java:310) at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2571)  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:455) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:829) at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2690)  at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:29) at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:649) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:171) at com.geniboys.sosyaaal.ExplorerActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ExplorerActivity.java:310) at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2571)  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:455) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:829) at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2690)  at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:29) at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:649) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:171) at com.geniboys.sosyaaal.ExplorerActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ExplorerActivity.java:310) at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2571)  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:455) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:829) at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2690)  at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:29) at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:649) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:171) at com.geniboys.sosyaaal.ExplorerActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ExplorerActivity.java:310) at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2571)  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:455) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:829) at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2690)  at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:29) at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:649) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:171) at com.geniboys.sosyaaal.ExplorerActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ExplorerActivity.java:310) at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2571)  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:455) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:829) at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2690)  at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:29) at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:649) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:171) at com.geniboys.sosyaaal.ExplorerActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ExplorerActivity.java:310) at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2571)  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:455) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:829) at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2690)  at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:29) at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:649) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:171) at com.geniboys.sosyaaal.ExplorerActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ExplorerActivity.java:310) at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2571)  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:455) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:829) at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2690)  at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:29) at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:649) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:171) at com.geniboys.sosyaaal.ExplorerActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ExplorerActivity.java:310) at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2571)  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:455) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:829) at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2690)  at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:29) at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:649) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:171) at com.geniboys.sosyaaal.ExplorerActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ExplorerActivity.java:310) at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2571)  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:455) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:829) at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2690)  at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:29) at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:649) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:171) at com.geniboys.sosyaaal.ExplorerActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ExplorerActivity.java:310) at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2571)  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:455) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:829) at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2690)  at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:29) at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:649) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:171) at com.geniboys.sosyaaal.ExplorerActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ExplorerActivity.java:310) at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2571)  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:455) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:829) at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2690)  at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:29) at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:649) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:171) at com.geniboys.sosyaaal.ExplorerActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ExplorerActivity.java:310) at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2571)  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:455) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:829) at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2690)  at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:29) at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:649) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:171) at com.geniboys.sosyaaal.ExplorerActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ExplorerActivity.java:310) at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2571)  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:455) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:829) at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2690)  at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:29) at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:649) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:171) at com.geniboys.sosyaaal.ExplorerActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ExplorerActivity.java:310) at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2571)  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:455) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:829) at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2690)  at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:29) at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:649) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:171) at com.geniboys.sosyaaal.ExplorerActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ExplorerActivity.java:310) at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2571)  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:233) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:200) at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:455) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:829) at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2690) .....
```

It goes like that

EDIT: Here is the part of code which overflows.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.explorer, menu);
    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();       

    mMenü = menu;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dont call invalidateOptionsMenu() from onCreateOptionsMenu it seems it is  leading to recursion...

Also share the code here

Comment: I have reached the character limit so I can't share the code and code itself is longer than character limit too. I can only share the onCreateOptionsMenu method if you want. I will try your suggestion

Comment: I have to wait until my tester replies. I will add method in a minute but it is only one line and just inflates menu